# access parent/original URL from a proxy in iframe from another domain (same origin policy)

Tags: javascript, iframe, onload

I have a page with an iframe that outputs a 3rd parties content in a list

Each item of content is in a `li` with a unique class `item-X`

```
<li class="item-1">
   <a href="item-1.html">View Item 1</a>
</li>
<li class="item-2">
   <a href="item-2.html">View Item 2</a>
</li>
```

I am looking for a way that:

User visits

```
www.parent-domain.com/?view_item=1
```

And the iframe reads this address, and simulates a `click` on the `item` being referred to.

The content inside the iframe uses an `onLoad('parent-domain.com/foo.html)` to load a proxy HTML file, to which I can add JS. (Presumably this is to get around same-origin policy).

Is this even possible?

- get query string from parent URL
- read value from iframe (inside a file inside `onLoad();`
- trigger click event on the `li a` with the class matching the value

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you pass the parents querystring to the iframe (using server side code or the like).

You can then easily retrieve "view_item" from the query string:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Then you simply find the link with the id and trigger the click:

```
var link = document.getElementbyId(getParameterByName("view_item"));
link.click();
```